# how to fetch data from json array field in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am using node.js with squel.js for SQL database.
I am storing array of string into one table field.

Let us say, My table name is like `XYZ`.
And my table data is like

```
id   col2
1    '["a", "b", "x", "y"]'
2    '["x", "y", "q"]'
3    '["q", "e"]'
4    '["p", "q"]'
```

Now i want to know how to make query for search like
if i want to how to make query if i want to fetch records like

1. If i want to fetch all records which contains like `["x", "y"]`. In this scenario i want expect result id 1 and 2.
2. If i want to fetch all records which contains like `["q"]`. In this scenario i want expect result 2 and 4.

Please help me here i stuck here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try to do? Did you really try? Did you look for any way in the da lib documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,just use `LIKE` can do it

For the first requirement,you can use

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE col2 LIKE `%"x"%` AND col2 LIKE `%"y"%`
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE col2 LIKE `%"x","y"%`
```

Since I do not know the format exactly,is it just check match `x` and `y`? Or just match `"x","y"` exactly?

For the second requirement,you can use

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE col2 LIKE `%"q"%`
```

Answer (score 0):

`col2` can be a `JSON` column, thus you can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(col2, JSON_ARRAY('x', 'y'));
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(col2, JSON_ARRAY('q'));
```

The second query would returns rows `2`, `3` and `4`, but I guess your expectation might be incorrectly stated, since `'q'` exists in the `col2` array for all of those.